# Menus in gnome-shell becomes slow on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gnome, gui, gnome-shell

During running OS, menus in applications becomes very slow and showed "Activities" tool is also very slow. I don't know what causes this behaviour because after start of system everything has normal speed. It helps me (in 80%) restart gnome-shell with

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.Shell /org/gnome/Shell org.gnome.Shell.Eval string:'global.reexec_self()'
```

I have Ubuntu 16.04.3 with LTS kernel and xserver.xorg and it runs on Dell latitude E5570 (it has Intel GPU).